# Edit GridView using BoundField Column in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using GridView for Showing Some Data with Editable Format. But When I am Editing the GridView row I don't get the Value of editable Textbox. Again I get the old Value.Please any one give some Suggestion.
Thanks in Advance...

**Aspx Code:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdAppSetting" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#1abc9c" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" CssClass="t-transform m-t-30" HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="5px"
            runat="server" OnRowCancelingEdit="grdAppSetting_RowCancelingEdit1" OnRowDeleting="grdAppSetting_RowDeleting" OnRowUpdating="grdAppSetting_RowUpdating"
            OnRowEditing="grdAppSetting_RowEditing" AutoGenerateColumns="false" BorderColor="#1abc9c"> 
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Key Name" HeaderText="Key Name" ReadOnly="true" ItemStyle-CssClass="p-l-10" ItemStyle-Width="100" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Value"  HeaderText="Value" ItemStyle-Height="40px" ItemStyle-Width="50%" ItemStyle-CssClass="p-l-10" ControlStyle-CssClass="form-control" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

**C# Code:**

```
 protected void grdAppSetting_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            string Value = ((grdAppSetting.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Controls[0]) as TextBox).Text;
            string KeyName = grdAppSetting.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text;
            if (appSettingsSection != null)
            {
                appSettingsSection.Settings[KeyName].Value = Value;
                configuration.Save();
            }
            grdAppSetting.EditIndex = -1;
            BindAppSettingGrid();
        }
```

Problem occurred in the following line,

```
string Value = ((grdAppSetting.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Controls[0]) as TextBox).Text;
```

Is this is correct to get the editable textbox value???

Comment: If you get the old value that probably means that you are binding the GridView data without an `IsPostBack` check. And if you are editing withing a GridView I would recommend TemplateFields.

Comment: Thank You So much VDWWD....I found my mistake...Actually I was binding the grid value when the page was Postback and not a Postback...Is this the actual problem I did.